# TopShelf указать от кого запускать службу

Tags: c#

Не хочу ставить на своей тачке сервис, есть ли возможность в коде указать имя от кого запускать и пароль, чтобы консольное приложение работало с указанными настройками. Как в настройках службы Windows

```
        HostFactory.Run(x =>                               //1
        {

            x.Service<MainWork>(s =>                      //2
            {                   
                s.ConstructUsing(name => new MainWork()); //3
                s.WhenStarted(tc => tc.Start());           //4 
                s.WhenStopped(tc => tc.Stop());            //5
            });
            x.RunAsLocalSystem();                          //6

            x.SetDescription("http:/index:osps:system:control");      //7
            x.SetDisplayName("srvc_control");                     //8
            x.SetServiceName("srvc_control");                     //9
        });
```

Comment: А разве TopShelf поддерживает консольные приложения? Я думал, он исключительно для сервисов.

Comment: он для удобной разработки. и да, его можно использовать как консольное приложение со всеми плюшками - консолью и прочим

Comment: ну, то есть если Вам сервис не нужен, то какая польза от TopShelf? Вдруг мне тоже нужно =)

Comment: на своей тачке то зачем сервис ставить. можно как с консолью работать, а уж на сервере устанавливаем

Comment: Если без топ-шелфа, то я обычно использую [Environment.UserInteractive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.userinteractive(v=vs.110).aspx) что бы можно было с одной и той же конфигурацией и без изменения года запускать как под собой (консоль) так и сервисом. Возможно TopShelf тоже поддерживает что то подобное

Answer (score 2):

изменить

```
x.RunAsLocalSystem();
```

на

`x.RunAs("DOMEN\login", "pass");`